# Python: Visual Studio Code not suggesting auto import

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

So I have `"python.analysis.indexing": true` in settings.json.

Any clue why `Session` from `sqlalchemy.orm` (a package two-levels deep) is not in the suggestion list?

[image]

while, `create_engine` from `sqlalchemy` (top level package) is?

[image]

Only symbols from a first level of a package in 3rd party libraries seem to be appearing in the suggestion list

Answer (score 2):

Usually, vscode only performs first-class retrieval. We can add the following content to make vscode perform deep retrieval:

```
"python.analysis.packageIndexDepths":[["sqlalchemy",2]],
```

In your case, `sqlalchemy.orm` is 2 level deep.

Of course, the load on hardware will also be greater.

You can also use `[["",2]]`, it will change default depth.

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2533#issuecomment-1089268739) in github for more information.